# How to rename Siri

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

Is there any way to rename Siri on the iPhone? I'm looking for any and all solutions, including Jailbreak tweaks. I love the new "Hey Siri" feature, but my SO and I both use iPhones with this feature, and when we're both laying in bed at night trying to use it, it leads to a bit of confusion between our devices...

Comment: Excellent way to work around the problem that many will have with strangers asking "Hey Siri" of anyone's phone that happens to be within voice range.